# Eclipse: library problem

Tags: java, eclipse, build

Eclipse is giving the following error:

```
The type org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpBuffers cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

For the following code:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log;


    public class FileServer {
        private FileServer() {
            Server server = new Server();
            SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
            connector.setPort(8080);
            server.addConnector(connector); //Error this line
        }
    }
```

I am using the following jar files:

```
jetty-io-7.1.6.v20100715.jar   
jetty-security-7.1.6.v20100715.jar
jetty-server-7.1.6.v20100715.jar
jetty-servlet-7.1.6.v20100715.jar
jetty-util-7.1.6.v20100715.jar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that the Jetty classes in your program internally depend on the `HttpBuffers` class in some way. You need to find and add the `jetty-http-7.1.6.v20100715.jar` file to your project's build/classpath - it contains the `HttpBuffers` class.

Comment: You could also switch to the `jetty-all` jar -- it contains all the required classes in a single archive. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate/jetty-all

Comment: @Uriah: Good call, that would probably make things easier to manage.

Comment: Same problem with http package happened for me.. this helped me to resolve. No direct use of the class from http library, but also I included to fix it.